# Webservices to monitor Windows Azure

Tags: web-services, azure

Does anybody of you know if there are any Webservices (or other interfaces) to monitor an, for example ASP.NET application, which is hosted within Windows Azure from a **NON** .NET environment?

Comment: Do you mean a non-Windows environment or an environment on which .NET is not allowed to be installed? Mono might be viable if not in the Windows environment.

Comment: No, I have to access it from a mobile device, so Mono is no option, but thanks.

Comment: What mobile platform do you need to monitor it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about monitoring things like performance counters and diagnostics (logging), those may be accessed from any language, as that information is ultimately stored in table Storage (you need to just set it up in your Windows Azure app as it starts up). Storage is accessed via a REST interface. Additionally, there are SDKs for [PHP](http://phpazure.codeplex.com/) and [Java](http://www.windowsazure4j.org/) to facilitate this. There are a few additional open source project I've seen as well - for instance, [Ruby](https://github.com/johnnyhalife/waz-storage).

For a desktop monitoring tool, check out Cerebrata's [Azure Diagnostics Manager](http://cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/).

Note: the Management API is also REST-based, so you can control deployments from other languages as well (e.g. scaling instances up/down, stopping/deleting a deployment, creating a new service, etc.). You'll see that the PHP SDK already wraps most of the Management API. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460799.aspx) for detailed API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Dirk, it depends on what you're trying to monitor. There are many partner products like [AzureWatch from Paraleap](http://www.paraleap.com/azurewatch) that can monitor applications in Windows Azure, or you could always write an application yourself to monitor your Windows Azure application using the Windows Azure APIs (try [AzureMonitor on CodePlex](http://azuremonitor.codeplex.com/)] as a start). You can find out more information about Monitoring on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff966484.aspx) and the [Windows Azure Managed Library Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179380.aspx).

Comment: AzureWatch also has an HTML5 app that allows for monitoring on the mobile devices (Android or IPhone)